# Animate background between original and set color

Tags: css, animation

I have HTML elements with random initial background colors.

I need to animate background color of selected element between original (initial) and new one.

I've been trying to use:

```
@keyframes blink-red {    
    0% { background-color: initial; color: initial; }
    100% { background-color: red; color: #000; }
}
```

But it seems to ignore "initial" setting.

I know it can be done with JavaScript by probing initial color, but would love to do it with pure css.

Code pen: https://codepen.io/kheim/pen/GGrMoj

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can omit keyframes with the `initial` values:

```css
.animate {
  padding: 1cm;
  animation: blink 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    background: green;
    color: #000;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="background: blue; color:#fff" class="animate">
Blue background
</div>
<div style="background: red; color:#fff" class="animate">
Blue background
</div>
```

Comment: OMG - I was not aware it's possible - thanks so much!

Comment: @user1038334, happy to help!