# Use keyframes animation to blink but also preserve original colour

Tags: html, css, d3.js, css-animations

I would like to create a blinking effect on some sectors of my pie chart that is created using d3js. The animation is incorporated by assigning the following css class to the path that represents the sector.

```
.blink{
  animation: blinking 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes blinking {
  0% { fill: red; }
  50% { fill: red; }
  51% { fill: white; }
  100% { fill: white; }
}
```

This causes the sector to blink, switching between red and white every second. However, this overrides the original colour. I want to instead preserve the colour and have it switching between red and the original colour. How can I achieve that? Note that the original colour depends on the value of my chart, so I do not know what it is beforehand and cannot just replace the colour white with whatever it would be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Animate background between original and set color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50777621/animate-background-between-original-and-set-color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind the change being animated, all you need to do is set `red` at `50%` without specifying anything else:

```css
.blink {
  animation: blinking 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes blinking {
  50% { fill: red; }
}
```

```html
<svg height="100" width="300">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" class="blink" fill="blue"/>
  <circle cx="250" cy="50" r="40" class="blink" fill="green"/>
</svg>
```

---

If you want the animation jumping between values (exactly as specified in `@keyframes`), it's only possible if the `fill` is inherited (from whatever the direct parent resolves as `fill`, using `inherit` as alternative color:

```css
.blink {
  animation: blinking 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes blinking {
  0% { fill: red; }
  50% { fill: red; }
  51% { fill: inherit; }
  100% { fill: inherit; }
}
```

```html
<svg height="100" width="100" fill="blue">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" class="blink" fill="green" />
</svg>
```

However, this solution has a disadvantage. It ignores any `fill` set directly on the element and animates to whatever the direct parent resolves for `fill` property. In other words, if you set `fill` to `blue` on the element and the parent resolves to `black`, it will alternate between `red` and `black`, ignoring `blue` altogether.
In the example above `green` is ignored.

---

Probably the only way to get exactly what you want, regardless of whether the current fill is inherited or own is by using JavaScript. Save the initial value and then animate between it and `red`

---

An alternate solution worth considering is using `color` instead of `fill` and setting `fill` to `currentColor`. This means your elements should have the `color` set to a particular color, not the `fill`. Here's a test:

```css
.blink {
  animation: blinking 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes blinking {
  0% { fill: red; }
  50% { fill: red; }
  51% { fill: currentColor; }
  100% { fill: currentColor; }
}
```

```html
<svg height="100" width="300" style="color: blue">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" class="blink" style="color: green" />
  <circle cx="250" cy="50" r="40" class="blink" />
</svg>
```

As you can see, `currentColor` works for both own and inherited values. Unfortunately, there is no implementation of its `fill` counterpart (e.g: `currentFill`). Yet.

Comment: The third option works perfectly for me, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can do by just setting a single frame in your `keyframe`. Like so:

```css
.blink{
  animation: blinking 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes blinking {
  50% {
    fill: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="128" height="128" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path class="icon blink" d="M30.148 5.588c-2.934-3.42-7.288-5.588-12.148-5.588-8.837 0-16 7.163-16 16s7.163 16 16 16c4.86 0 9.213-2.167 12.148-5.588l-10.148-10.412 10.148-10.412zM22 3.769c1.232 0 2.231 0.999 2.231 2.231s-0.999 2.231-2.231 2.231-2.231-0.999-2.231-2.231c0-1.232 0.999-2.231 2.231-2.231z"></path>
</svg>
```